# FizzBuzz Javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm doing this FizzBuzz challenge and I've made a mistake but cannot identify it. I'm wanting numbers from 1-100 to display on a web browser. The numbers that are divisible by 3 should say "fizz", the numbers divisible by 5 should say "buzz", and the numbers divisible by both 5and3 should say "FizzBuzz." **I'm unable to get the browser to display the words, and for some reason it only displays the numbers.**

```js
function fizzbuzz() {
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  var displayHTML = "";

  for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("FizzBuzz")
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log("buzz")
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      console.log("Fizz")
    } else {
      console.log(i)
    }


    displayHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
  }
  display.innerHTML = displayHTML
}
```

```html
<body onload="fizzbuzz()">
  <div id="display">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you're only ever adding `"<p>" + i + "</p>"` to your display HTML, where `i` will always be a number. You need to instead change `"<p>" + i + "</p>"` based on the if-statements that trigger before this code

Comment: ``console.log()`` just prints a debug to the browser's Javascript console (not the output page) which is why you aren't seeing your text. As @Nick says you want to set the appropriate string in your conditionals and then output it when you do the ``<p>...</p>``.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are concatenating i, the counter to displayHTML here `displayHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p>";`

Instead save the value you want to print in a variable on conditional check and then concatenate it afterwards

```
var result = '';
for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      result = "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      result = "buzz";
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      result = "Fizz";
    } else {
      result = i;
    }


    displayHTML += "<p>" + result + "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When a condition is true, you can set the result in a variable and then print your displayHTML element.

```js
function fizzbuzz() {
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  var divisible = "";
  var displayHTML = "";

  for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      divisible = "FizzBuzz";
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      divisible = "Buzz";
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      divisible = "Fizz";
    } else {
      divisible = "";
    }

    displayHTML += "<p>" + i + ":" + divisible + "</p>";
  }
  display.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', displayHTML); 
}

fizzbuzz();
```

Comment: Its NOT recemended to use `.innerHTML` read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: From MDN => Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, what do you recommend instead?

Answer (score -2):

```
const fancy = function(i, output) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        let output = '';
        if (i % 3 === 0) output += 'fizz';
        if (i % 5 === 0) output += 'buzz';
        console.log(output || i);
    }
};

fancy();
```